# Call child class method using dynamic keyword

Tags: c#-4.0, inheritance, dynamic

I have several classes all implementing an interface `IBar`. Those classes are `BarA`, `BarB`, `BarC`.

I also have a base class `Foo`:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    void Do(IBar bar)
    {
        Handle((dynamic)bar);
    }

    void Handle(IBar bar)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Fallback Scenario");
    }
}
```

I want a child class `FooChild` like follows:

```
class FooChild : Foo
{
    void Handle(BarA bar) {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Handling BarA");
    }

    void Handle(BarB bar) {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Handling Bar");
    }
}
```

No I want to do the following, but I don't get the result I expect

```
var foo = new FooChild();
foo.Handle(new BarA()); // expected: Handling BarA, actual: Fallback Scenario
foo.Handle(new BarB()); // expected: Handling BarB, actual: Fallback Scenario
foo.Handle(new BarC()); // expected: Fallback Scenario, actual: Fallback Scenario
```

I can solve it by moving the `Do(IBar bar)` method to the `FooChild` class, but I don't want to do that. I might have 10 `Foo` childs and don't want to repeat that code. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
void Do(IBar bar)
{
    dynamic dynamicThis = this;
    dynamicThis.Handle((dynamic) bar);
}
```

That way the method will be found against the *actual* type of `this`. Otherwise, the compiler remembers that the method was called from `Foo`, and only treats the *argument* dynamically, finding methods which would have been available from `Foo` with the actual type of `bar`. You want methods which would have been available from the actual type of `this`, as well as using the actual type of `bar` (via the cast to `dynamic`).

(You'll need to make the `Handle` methods public though.)

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your answer!
It worked almost; I had to keep the (dynamic) cast in the method invocation to make it work succesfully.

Comment: @avanwieringen: Ah, yes - otherwise it would still try to use the compile-time type. I'll fix my answer for future visitors.

Comment: So if I am correct, the dynamic keyword will match based on runtime knowledge and not on compile-time knowledge?

Comment: @avanwieringen: That's the behaviour of dynamic expressions, yes. But the compiler retains any compile-time knowledge it *does* have as part of those expressions - so if you had `Method(x, y)` where the compile-time type of `x` is `dynamic` but the compile-time type of `y` was just `object`, it would only match methods where the second parameter was `object`, regardless of the execution-time type of `y`.

Comment: Noteworthy:  This did not work when my FooChild was a nested private class (as for a unit test).  Making it public worked.  Curious why the RuntimeBinder was not able to resolve the method it correctly, even though it looked fine via the debugger.

Comment: @emragins: It depends on where you were trying to use it from.

Comment: I created a gist with the scenario reduced to show the error: https://gist.github.com/emragins/1eb520a44743ed0a0593098e69a17155

Comment: @emragins: Right - in that case you're trying to use a member declared in a type which isn't visible to the code that is trying to invoke the member. The dynamic feature is *designed* for that to fail.

Comment: Put that way it makes a lot of sense.  #1 as always. :)